# Windows 8- Mail App

Tags: windows-8-mail-app

I am having an issue with removing an email account that no longer exists; from my Windows 8- mail app. I have recently restored my computer to factory defaults for other reasons, and now that I am updating my accounts into my mail app, there is one account that is still shown but has an error that Email requires attention. The email is requesting I sign in to update details, but that account no longer exists and I have no idea how to delete that from the mail app. I have no options under the normal way of deleting an account!

Answer (score 0):

Follow up Settings > Change PC Settings > Accounts > Other Accounts
Go there and unlink your account. You can add you new account from there its